# Convert timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert timestamp column to the following format in PostgreSQL:

```
2/28/2018
```

I've tried:

```
to_char((sr.created_at), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

but that gives me:

```
02/28/2018
```

Is there way to do that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You want to remove `0`?

Comment: Yeah, I want to remove 0 from the month.

Comment: What do you want for 1st Jan 2019? `1/1/2019` or `1/01/2019` ?

Comment: I want 1/1/2019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the [**FM**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) prefix to suppress leading zeroes.

```
knayak=# select TO_CHAR(DATE '2019-01-01','FMMM/FMDD/YYYY');
 to_char
----------
 1/1/2019
(1 row)
```